# "class JavaLaunchHelper is loacted in two places..." is shown when launching java web start in mac 10.8.x

Tags: java, java-web-start

This error is shown when running the command(javaws "jnlp-file") in terminal in Mac 10.8.x with latest JRE 7 update 40:

> Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented on both /Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java and Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib . One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Any command execution with `javaws` shows the same error message and to avoid this either of them specified in the path should be deleted, but it's not a user scenario.

Is there any other way to avoid this? Below is my code

```
        final StringBuffer info = new StringBuffer();
        final StringBuffer error = new StringBuffer();
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(javaws <jnlp-file>);
        final StreamPumper outPumper = new StreamPumper(process.getInputStream(), info);
        final StreamPumper errPumper = new StreamPumper(process.getErrorStream(), error);
        outPumper.start();
        errPumper.start();
        process.waitFor();
        outPumper.join();
        errPumper.join();
```

Comment: This is what i have found

http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021205

It should be fixed by oracle
Hope it will resolve the issue

Comment: That bug report said that it was solved in 7u60, but I'm running 7u65 and I'm still getting it. That bug report is incredibly vague - what makes you think it's related to your issue?

Comment: Actually, just realized I'm running 6u65. Further, the same program is launching just fine on another mostly identical computer running 7u45. So I'm reaching the conclusion that bug report has absolutely nothing to do with this message.